# MVC Remote Attribute Required Double Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I'm having an issue with the Remote Attribute on my ViewModel.

Basically I have a Job Title, I have it set up that if you want to edit one, it takes the current Job Titles and populates a drop down with them.

If you pick one from the list it makes an ajax call to return a partial with the selected Job Title's data.

Here is the Title property of the Edit Job Title Model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Title")]
    [Remote("IsUniqueTitle", "Administration", HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = "SelectedJobTitleId", ErrorMessage = "Job Title with title already exists. Please try another one")]
    [IsUniqueTitle("SelectedJobTitleId", ErrorMessage = "Job Title with title already exists. Please try another one")]
    [MaxLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Title can not be more than 32 characters")]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

It's the usual usage to check if something with that name already exists.
That's why it takes an id of a Job Titles to it can skips the selected one when it checks uniqueness.

Here is the Action in the controller

```
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("isuniquetitle")]
    public JsonResult IsUniqueTitle(string title, int selectedJobTitleId = 0)
    {
        var response = _jobTitleService.IsUniqueTitle(
            new IsUniqueNameRequest(selectedJobTitleId, title));

        var result = false;

        if (response.Success)
        {
            result = response.Entity;
        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The big issue I am having is that when I click the submit button it does the check against this action, but then I am having to click the submit button again to actually post the form to the server and it makes the changes.

I have looked everywhere and can't find anything like it. Has anyone come up against this problem?

Comment: Not sure about this but try Change `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that one made no difference :(